# Why is my Rust program 4x slower than a Go program doing the same bitwise and I/O operations?

Tags: go, rust

I have a Rust program that implements a brute-force parity check for 64-bit unsigned integers:

```rust
use std::io;
use std::io::BufRead;

fn parity(mut num: u64) -> u8 {
    let mut result: u8 = 0;
    while num > 0 {
        result = result ^ (num & 1) as u8;
        num = num >> 1;
    }
    result
}

fn main() {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    let mut num: u64;
    let mut it = stdin.lock().lines();
    // skip 1st line with number of test cases
    it.next();
    for line in it {
        num = line.unwrap().parse().unwrap();
        println!("{}", parity(num));
    }
}
```

When I feed it with input file containing 1000000 unsigned integers:

```
$ rustc parity.rs
$ time cat input.txt | ./parity &> /dev/null
cat input.txt  0.00s user 0.02s system 0% cpu 4.178 total
./parity &> /dev/null  3.87s user 0.32s system 99% cpu 4.195 total
```

And here comes a surprise - the effectively same program in Go does 4x faster:

```
$ go build parity.go
$ time cat input.txt | ./parity &> /dev/null
cat input.txt  0.00s user 0.03s system 3% cpu 0.952 total
./parity &> /dev/null  0.63s user 0.32s system 99% cpu 0.955 total
```

Here's the code in Go:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

func parity(line string) uint64 {
    var parity uint64
    u, err := strconv.ParseUint(line, 10, 64)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for u > 0 {
        parity ^= u & 1
        u >>= 1
    }
    return parity
}

func main() {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    // skip line with number of cases
    if !scanner.Scan() {
        // panic if there's no number of test cases
        panic("missing number of test cases")
    }
    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Println(parity(scanner.Text()))
    }
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "reading standard input:", err)
    }
}
```

Versions:

```
$ rustc --version
rustc 1.7.0
$ go version
go version go1.6 darwin/amd64
```

Sample of input file, first line contains number of input values in the file:

```
8
7727369244898783789
2444477357490019411
4038350233697550492
8106226119927945594
1538904728446207070
0
1
18446744073709551615
```

Why do the Rust and Go programs I've written have such a dramatic difference in performance? I expected Rust to be a bit faster than Go in this case. Am I doing something wrong in my Rust code?

Comment: The Rust code will be significantly faster if you compile with optimisations: `rustc -O parity.rs`.

Comment: Compiling with optimizations is described in the [Getting Started](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/getting-started.html) section of [*The Rust Programming Language*](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/README.html), the section immediately after the 1-page introduction.

Comment: I get it taking 3 seconds unoptimised and 0.45 seconds optimised in Rust, and 0.6 seconds in Go.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'd recommend using the built-in [`count_ones`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i64.html#method.count_ones) method. Looks [like this](http://is.gd/tjLsyF).

Comment: @Shepmaster thanks for the suggestion, good to know!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're not compiling with optimisation.
try

```
$ rustc -O parity.rs
```

Comment: You're so right, thanks! For others who will read this - there's another way to set optimization level - `rustc -C opt-level=3 parity.rs`, and `-O` is a shortcut for `-C opt-level=2`.

Comment: you can also use `cargo build --release`, I find it more convenient than rustc